# Sound is muted on start up

Tags: sound, 13.04, mute

System sound is muted by default after startup even if I didn't set it muted before shutting down.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 x64 bit in my HP Pavilion G6.

How do I track this problem?
How this can be solved?

Comment: Hi niran, for that specific HP model, please see the duplicate link provided. The answers there will help you solve and track the problem down.